# How to remove "OK" button from Dialog fragment in Android

Tags: android-dialogfragment, onitemselectedlistener

I'm trying to remove the OK button completely so that an item is automatically clicked when selected. I noticed that this is Android's preferred way of doing it. I don't need a "cancel" button because I want to prevent null selected.

Dialog Fragment

```
public class SingleChoiceClass extends 
DialogFragment {`

final CharSequence[] items = {"b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"};
String selection;
@NonNull
@Override


public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());`


builder.setTitle("Choose").setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    switch (arg1){
        case 0:
            selection = (String) items[arg1];
            break;
        case 1:
            selection = (String) items[arg1];
            break;
        case 2:
            selection = (String) items[arg1];
            break;
        case 3:
            selection = (String) items[arg1];
            break;

            }

    }
}).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


        // Display toast with the user's selection
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your choice is : " + selection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    return builder.create();
 }
}
```

The code works fine as it is, I just want to get selected item without having to click "OK" button. It saves user's time.

Comment: To make it easier for answerers, or others with similar problems, please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: Thanks @Nathan Tuggy, the code works just fine. I just want to get selected item (when selected) without having to click an "OK" button to perform action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the Android recommended way of doing this but I finally figured out a way of achieving the exact behavior I want.

```
public class SingleChoiceClass extends 
DialogFragment {

final CharSequence[] items = {"b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"};
String selection;
@NonNull
@Override

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
final MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

builder.setTitle("Choose")
    .setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
switch (arg1){
    case 0:
        selection = (String) items[arg1];
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + selection,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Do your magic
        dismiss();
        break;
    case 1:
        selection = (String) items[arg1];
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + selection,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Do your magic
        dismiss();
        break;
    case 2:
        selection = (String) items[arg1];
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + selection,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Do your magic
        dismiss();
        break;
    case 3:
        selection = (String) items[arg1];
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + selection,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Do your magic
        dismiss();
        break;
        }
}
}).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        //Exit
        activity.finish(); //Or find a way to relaunch Dialog
    }
});
return builder.create();
 }
}
```