# Android Studio - How to dismiss dialog box

Tags: android, android-studio

Just wondering how I would dismiss the dialog box when an option is selected.

Here is the code

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.launch_voip_call) {
        Utils.startCall(this, contact);
        return true;
    } 
    else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.launch_attachment){

        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);

        View choiceView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_image_source_chooser, null);

        ImageButton cameraButton = (ImageButton) choiceView.findViewById(R.id.cameraButton);

        ImageButton galleryButton = (ImageButton) choiceView.findViewById(R.id.galleryButton);

        cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(SingleConversationActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
                cameraIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_CONTACT_JID", contact.getJid());
                startActivity(cameraIntent);

            }
        });
```

Comment: `alertDialog.dismiss();` onclick section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);

                LayoutInflater inflater = YourActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
                View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_image_source_chooser, null);
                dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

               ImageButton cameraButton = (ImageButton) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.cameraButton);

    ImageButton galleryButton = (ImageButton) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.galleryButton);


                final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();

                cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                         alertDialog.dismiss();
                         Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(SingleConversationActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
            cameraIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_CONTACT_JID", contact.getJid());
            startActivity(cameraIntent);

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yourDialogInstance.dismiss();
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html

Answer (score 0):

use `alertDialog.dismiss()` inside `onClick()` method.

also, to show the dialog, `alertDialog.show()`

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33889998/4924793)

Try adding `dialogBuilder.dismiss();`